# Is there a way to remove old pipelines every 15th day in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

Is there a way to schedule removing of old pipelines created every 15th day in gitlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no feature to expire pipelines periodically/automatically, but you can use [scheduled pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) to run a job on a schedule. You can use that to schedule a job which cleans up pipelines in the project (or other projects).

You would have to write a script that implements the logic according to your rules. You can script against [the pipelines API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/pipelines.html) to get the age of a pipeline as well as delete it when it meets your criteria.